# ubuntu 14.04 install with custom swap size using LVM?

Tags: encryption, swap, lvm

I want to install ubuntu 14.04 with LVM and encryption. But the problem is that my computer has a large RAM (16GB) and a small SDD disk (60GB). So I think only a small amount of space for swap is enough but I'm not sure how I can specify the amount of space for the swap partition. I selected "something else" choice, but I don't think I can setup LVM there...

Thanks

Comment: There is tutorial about lvm https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM, it is little outdated but did you tried it ?

Comment: Since you have so much RAM and so little SSD you might consider not having swap at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot Ubuntu ISO, select "Try Ubuntu" to start a desktop
- Run gparted and create a partition of type "lvm2 pv" (this is your LVM physical volume)
- Start a terminal:

  - `sudo -s` to become root
  - Create a volume group on your LVM PV partition:

    ```
    vgcreate vg /dev/sdaX
    ```
  - Create your LVM logical volumes (change GB sizes as you wish):

    ```
    lvcreate -n root -L 6g vg
    lvcreate -n swap -L 1g vg
    ```
- Start the Ubuntu installer ("Install Ubuntu.."):

  - Select "Something else" at partitioning.
  - Select your root logical volume, click "Change", set "Use as" = "ext4", "Mount point" = /
  - Select swap, click "Change", set "Use as" = "swap area"